# Drawing lines between nodes in directed graph. UML Classes?

Tags: c++, graph, uml, directed-graph

I am not sure if I am on the right lines of thought here so I am really just looking for someone to tell me how wrong I am.

Basically I am looking to create a class drawing tool, pretty much like any UML software. I am looking for 90 degree line connections. It must draw lines to each inheriting / connected class and draw around any obstacles.

My first thought was to use pathfinding to draw the initial line then to pad out the line to make them 90 degrees but then I realised that the inheriting classes are basically just creating a graph so I could use something to draw the connections themselves.

Is this how it is done? Does anyone have any experience in this and can give me some insight?

Thanks.

Comment: Although [Wikipedia: Graph drawing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_drawing) references 2 articles describing orthogonal layout algorithms, I'd use Google query `graph orthogonal layout routing algorithm` to find some more

Comment: Seems to be bringing up exactly what I need. Much appreciated!